# Converting list of arrays to array of arrays (preserving shape of subarrays) in R

Tags: r, arrays, list

I have a list of 3 arrays. Each array has dims 10, 10, 3. I would like to convert this list to array and I would like to preserve the shape features of sub-arrays. In other words, I would like to have an array with dims 3,10,10,3 instead of list of 3 arrays with dims 10,10,3. The order of arrays shall be preserved.

Here is an example list:

```
a1 <- array(c(1:100), dim = c(10,10,3))
a2 <- array(c(1:100), dim = c(10,10,3))
a3 <- array(c(1:100), dim = c(10,10,3))

lis <- list()
lis[[1]] <- a1
lis[[2]] <- a2
lis[[3]] <- a3
```

The structure of the list is following:

```
[[1]]
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

, , 2

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

, , 3

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

[[2]]
, , 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

etc.
```

I tried following approach:

```
tarray <- function(x) aperm(x, rev(seq_along(dim(x))))
ar <- tarray(array(unlist(lis), c(3, 10, 10, 3)))
```

The dims seemed fine, although the output did not:

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1   31   61   91   21   51   81   11   41    71
[2,]    1   31   61   91   21   51   81   11   41    71
[3,]    1   31   61   91   21   51   81   11   41    71

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    4   34   64   94   24   54   84   14   44    74
[2,]    4   34   64   94   24   54   84   14   44    74
[3,]    4   34   64   94   24   54   84   14   44    74

, , 3, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    7   37   67   97   27   57   87   17   47    77
[2,]    7   37   67   97   27   57   87   17   47    77
[3,]    7   37   67   97   27   57   87   17   47    77

, , 4, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   10   40   70  100   30   60   90   20   50    80
[2,]   10   40   70  100   30   60   90   20   50    80
[3,]   10   40   70  100   30   60   90   20   50    80

, , 5, 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]   13   43   73    3   33   63   93   23   53    83
[2,]   13   43   73    3   33   63   93   23   53    83
[3,]   13   43   73    3   33   63   93   23   53    83
```

I would like to have the array output which looks like this:

```
, , 1, 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

, , 2, 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100

, , 3, 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100


, , 4, 1

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    1   11   21   31   41   51   61   71   81    91
 [2,]    2   12   22   32   42   52   62   72   82    92
 [3,]    3   13   23   33   43   53   63   73   83    93
 [4,]    4   14   24   34   44   54   64   74   84    94
 [5,]    5   15   25   35   45   55   65   75   85    95
 [6,]    6   16   26   36   46   56   66   76   86    96
 [7,]    7   17   27   37   47   57   67   77   87    97
 [8,]    8   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88    98
 [9,]    9   19   29   39   49   59   69   79   89    99
[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You say you want your array to be 3x10x10x3 but your output shows a 10x10x?x1. I'm not sure what is the expected output.

Comment: Have a look at [How to turn list into an array in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51817048/10488504)

Answer (score 1):

Use `unlist` and `array`.

```
array(unlist(lis), dim = c(10,10,3,3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `simplify2array`:

```
simplify2array(lis)
```